# How to test Google+ sign-in with Robotium?

Tags: android, google-plus, robotium, black-box-testing

I created an LoginActivity using Android Studio "new project" wizard. I added dependency on Robotium and wrote a simple test, extending from `InstrumentationTestCase`:

```
    launchActivity("com.my.package", LoginActivity.class, new Bundle());
    solo.waitForActivity(LoginActivity.class, 1000);
    solo.clickOnText("Sign in"); //inside my Activity
    assertTrue("Not G+", solo.waitForActivity("GrantCredentialsWithAclActivity", 4000));
    solo.clickOnText("Sign in"); //on Google+ dialog
```

But the "Not G+" assertion fails.

I've found from dumpsys that `com.google.android.gms/.auth.login.GrantCredentialsWithAclActivity` is Google+ sign-in activity on my device. How it translates to `name` parameter from `solo.waitForActivity(name, timeout)`? Am I even able to click anything on Google+ dialog?

Comment: Sorry, but I have never have used Google Play Services' authentication system. However, based on your description, that's not a dialog, but rather an activity from Play Services, and you cannot interact with that using Robotium (AFAIK), because it is not part of your app. UIAutomator is for integration testing, and so perhaps you can test this path using UIAutomator.